# Limit of Multivariable Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, fourier-series

If I have some Fourier Series representation of a function with $x$ period of $2L$

> $$G(x,y) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left[a_n \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right) + b_n \cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)\right]f_n(y)$$

Where each of the $f_n(y) \to 0 $ as $y \to \infty$ do we necessarily have that

> $$\lim_{y \to \infty} G(x,y) = 0$$

I do not know the relevant analysis -- maybe we are not always allowed to take termwise limits of an infinite sum? Is there a general result that applies here? How might I go about calculating limits of sums like this, is there a particular method that is usually applied?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, guess in your case you are correct. You can see for example "Elementary Properties of Limits of Functions" (Ch.6, p.156) in S. Krantz Real Analysis and Foundations.